# duplicate markers when displaying them using mapbox geolocation

Tags: vue.js, mapbox

I have a search engine on my page in which when looking for a location I add a marker which the user can move, the problem is that every time I look for a new location, it adds a marker for each one, how can I solve this so that only show me a markup every time I search for a location?

This is the code that does this

```js
    const geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
          mapboxgl: mapboxgl,                                                                               
          accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
          marker: false
        })
        geocoder.on('result', e => {
          const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
            draggable: true
          })
          .setLngLat(e.result.center)
          .addTo(map)
          marker.on('dragend', (e) => {
          })
        })
        map.addControl(geocoder)
```